# Need SQL Query for insert satisfying below requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am still a newbie to MS-SQL and not familiar with complex queries of it. I am trying to find different ways and easy method to write query for below requirement without using cursor or anything that will degrade performance.

I have a linking table table1 with 4 columns.
say A, B, C, D.

B is an ID of book1 and C is an ID of book2.

I have another table table2 (BooksInformation table) with few columns.
say W (BookID), X, Y, Z

column B and C of table1 are nothing but refers(foreign key) to column W(primary key) of table2. So, there will be two entries in table2 for every one record in table1.

We have another table table3 with few columns
say E, F, G, H, I, J.

Now, Column G (BookID) of table3 is foreign key to column W (primary key) of table2.
Column F has **studentID**

Now, I want to insert rows for student in table3 when below condition satisfies:

1. If a student contains Book1 and if he does not contain Book2.
2. If a student contains Book2 and if he does not contain Book1.
3. Make sure IDs of Book1 and Book2 are present in table2.

Book1 and Book2 links can be found from table1.

Table1

```
    Field   Type    Null
A   Table1ID    int(10) No
B   BookIDFrom  char(20)    No
C   BookIDTo    char(20)    No
D   Desc    varchar(20) No
```

Table2

```
    Field   Type    Null
W   Table2ID    char(20)    No
X   BookName    char(20)    No
Y   BookDesc    char(20)    No
Z   Amount  decimal(10,6)   No
```

Table3

```
    Field   Type    Null
E   Table3ID    char(20)    No
F   StudentID   int(10) No
G   BookID  char(20)    No
H   Batch   char(20)    No
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
select *, tb3.StudentID, subtable.BookIDTo 
from table3 tb3 
right join 
    (select StudentID, tb1.BookIDTo 
     from table1 tb1 
     join table3 ED 
     on tb1.BookIDFrom = ED.BookID) subtable 
on tb3.BookID = subtable.BookIDTo 
and tb3.StudentID = subtable.StudentID 
and tb3.BookID is null
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Table1 = TableA?

Comment: @LordBaconPants yes. my bad. updated tableA as table1.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne I am still struggling to figure out where to start from.

Comment: Start with a few things: 1. Write a SELECT statement. 2. Write a select statement with a join. 3. Add some sample data. You might want to read this also: https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/deFault.asp

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - as of now, I have something like below                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 select *, tb3.StudentID, subtable.BookIDTo from table3  tb3 with (nolock) right join
(select StudentID, tb1.BookIDTo from table1  tb1 with (nolock)
 join table3 ED with (nolock)
on tb1.BookIDFrom = ED.BookID) subtable on tb3.BookID = subtable.BookIDTo and 
tb3.StudentID = subtable.StudentID and tb3.BookID is null

Comment: I've put your SQL into the question. Firstly... why all the `nolock`. I suggest you remove them unless you have a very good resaon. Your requirements are ambiguous: Does this: _If a student contains Book1 and if he does not contain Book2._ Is Book1 the book name? Can a student have multiple rows? Does this mean on a given row or across all rows?

Comment: Problem is not tough,lil more explanation is needed.There is no harm is inusing correct TableName and column name.Also write purpose in 1-2 lines.specially explain Table1,BookIDFrom and BookIDTO is not clear at all.what you want to insert in Table3,one row or several row.what is Book1 &Book2.what do you mean by "If a student contains Book1 and if he does not contain Book2.".

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes I can remove nolock as of now. when I say student contains Book1, it means if in a table3, studentID like 1234 is mapped to BookIDFrom (BookID in table3) then 1234 should also to mapped or have an entry to corresponding BookIDTo from table1 in table3 and vice versa. It means studentID 1234 can have multiple entries in table3.

Comment: I'm sorry I just don't understand what you're saying.